# Saving XElement asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, xelement, xmlwriter

I am currently writing an XML Tree (`XElement`) to a file synchronously using `XmlWriter`, specifically via [`XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.writeto(v=vs.110).aspx) on the root element.  I'm trying to make that asynchronous (with an await).  `XmlWriter` can be made asynchronous (`XmlWriterSettings.Async = true`), and has an async version for many of its methods. However, it doesn't have methods to write an `XElement` (async or not), and there is no async version of `XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter)`.

What API can be used to write an `XElement` to a file asynchronously?

Comment: I really doubt there is a benefit to doing a cpu bound bit of work like that in an async fashion. `Task.Run()` is an option but I think it would be more detrimental to performance than beneficial unless the value was a truly huge amount of data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; however, If it was such a bad idea, why does XmlWriter have so many async methods (I'm still perplexed as to why there are none to write XElement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlWriter` has a method [`XmlWriter.WriteNodeAsync(XmlReader, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161202.aspx) to which you can pass the `XmlReader` returned by [`XNode.CreateReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299560.aspx) e.g. like so:

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static async Task WriteToAsync(this XContainer element, Stream stream, bool defAttr = true, bool indent = false)
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Async = true,
            CloseOutput = false,
            Indent = indent,
        };          

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            await writer.WriteNodeAsync(reader, defAttr);
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you have some `Stream stream` you could write to it as follows:

```
await element.WriteToAsync(stream, false, true);
```

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xEiTZr).